# Passing FormArray to a child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to build a formArray with a child component where the formArray is out of my child component. The structure of my code is following

I used the reactive form in angular 7.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div [formGroup]="myForm">
 <div formArrayName="myArray">
   <my-child-component [parentForm]="myForm"><my-child-component/>
 </div>
<div>
```

I get some error because Angular doesn't know the controlFormName set in my child component even if, i declare them in my formArray, myArray. Someone can help me please /!\

Comment: mate, you will have to put some code (.ts) in to help us help you :)

Comment: You can forget formArray Name and pass as `[parentForm]="myForm.get('myArray')"`. NOTE: It's possible you need has a getter in your component `get myArray(){ return this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray}` and pass as `[parentForm]="myArray"`